# Custom Actions "not available for your language or region"

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have crated a dialogflow agent, integrated in actions on google and tried it on test environment. I am located on Singapore, it can work on my device. When others who has been added as viewer on project and is located on Kazakhstan cannot access the actions. Get the message " isn't available on devices set up for your language or country."

We already tried setting up the default language to English(US) and different region.Still have problem.

I would really appreciate for any help. Thanks

Comment: Have the people who are located in khazkhstan used the action in the actions on google simulator? To be able to test on a real device you need to use the simulator atleast once. If that is not it, you can also have a look in the actions on google settings to see of your action is set to be available in khazkhstan.